# Set relationship across two tables

Tags: phpmyadmin

How can I use phpmyadmin to set relationships for column data across two tables?

Let's say I have a `user table`

**id** | **userName**

and a `order table`

**id** | **customerID** | **customerName**

how can I tell phpmyadmin that the `customerName` is always equal to the `userName` based on the `customerID` even if the username gets updated?

*Is such a thing possible and if yes whats the relationship called?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't or should not.  If that is what you want don't have a CustomerName field, only have a UserName field and always join to the User table to get the name.  What you describe is a database design issue.  Understand what "Third Normal Form" is.